Store key-value pairs with Gradle Kotlin DSL
I am trying to organize my code and get rid of some unnecessary repetitions. Current code:
android {
    defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField("String", "VAR_1", "\"1\"")
        buildConfigField("String", "VAR_2", "\"2\"")
        //....
        buildConfigField("String", "VAR_10", "\"10\"")
    }
}

I want to load variable names and values from another config.gradle.kts file:
val vars = mapOf(
    "VAR_1" to "1",
    "VAR_2" to "2",
    //...
    "VAR_10" to "10",
)
project.extra.set("vars", vars)

So eventually, I will be able to do something like this:
apply(from = "config.gradle.kts")

android {
    defaultConfig {
        project.extra["vars"].forEach { entry -> 
            buildConfigField("String", entry.key, "${entry.value}")
        }
    }
}

But when I try this, I keep getting all sorts of can not cast java.Util.Collections.SingletonMap to kotlin.Pair.

It turned out there is nothing wrong with my code. Once I started abstracting the issue to post it here, I figured out that I was just doing some wrong casting.
I am leaving this for future references:
apply(from = "config.gradle.kts")

android {
    defaultConfig {
        project.extra["vars"].forEach { entry -> 
            buildConfigField("String", entry.key, "${entry.value}")
        }
    }
}

